# How to add the cluster ID to each component (igraph)

Tags: r, data.table, igraph

I know how to use igraph package in R to obtain connected components in two columns in data set.

data set

```
library(data.table)
df = fread(
"rn  A      B
1:   11     6
2:   12     6
3:   11     7
4:   13     2
5:   12     7
6:   12     8
7:   17     2
8:   13     1")[, rn := NULL][]

library(igraph)
g = graph_from_data_frame(df)
cluster = clusters(g)
list = groups(cluster)
```

What I want to do next is to assign the cluster ID to each **connected component**.

```
     A      B    ID
1:   11     6    1
2:   12     6    1
3:   11     7    1
4:   13     2    2
5:   12     7    1
6:   12     8    1
7:   17     2    2
8:   13     1    2
```

I hope this makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the membership by doing either:

```
df$ID <- cluster$membership[as.character(df$A)]
```

Or

```
df$ID <- cluster$membership[as.character(df$B)]
```

Both should give:

```
df
#    A B ID
#1: 11 6  1
#2: 12 6  1
#3: 11 7  1
#4: 13 2  2
#5: 12 7  1
#6: 12 8  1
#7: 17 2  2
#8: 13 1  2
```

Comment: Similarly, could put the membership relation in a table and "update join" on it: `memDT = data.table(id = as.integer(names(cluster$mem)), g = as.integer(cluster$mem)); df[memDT, on=.(A = id), g := i.g]`

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.